# Can you control how Excel translates your Pivot Table to MDX when connected to Analysis Services?

Tags: excel, pivot-table, ssas, mdx

When creating a report in Excel from a pivot table created by connecting to a cube in Analysis Services, the MDX sent to the server to query the report is very inefficient. The inefficiency stems from the fact that it generates a NONEMPTY statement but does not supply a measure to look up the non-null values in. Is there any way to control this behavior? It currently causes a report to take 30 minutes to be returned, however if I run the query and supply a measure to the NonEmpty clause, it returns in seconds.